# compilation error for auto comparison

Tags: c++

my code compiles perfectly in code blocks but shows a lot of error during compilation in eclips. Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstdlib>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include<ctime>
 #include<iomanip>
 #include<vector>
 using namespace std;
 int myrandom (int i) { return std::rand()%i;}
 int card_to_move(vector<string> input) // function to check if the players    has the same suit
{
int i =0; int j;
char suit = input.at(0).at(0);
for (auto comparison : input)
    {
        if (comparison.at(0) == suit){
                                        i++;
                                        }
        else{j=i;break;}
    }return j;
}
bool are_all_same_suit(vector<string> input)// function to compare suits
{
char suit = input.at(0).at(0);
for (auto comparison : input)
    {
        if (comparison.at(0) != suit) return false;
    }
return true;
}
int main()
{

srand ( unsigned ( std::time(0) ) );
vector<string> myvector;
vector<string>all_cards;
vector<string>player_0;
vector<string>player_1;
vector<string>player_2;
vector<string>player_3;
vector<string>player_4;
vector<string>cards=    {"DA","DK","DQ","DJ","D2","D3","D4","D5","D6","D7","D8","D9","D10",
                        "HA","HK","HQ","HJ","H2","H3","H4","H5","H6","H7","H8","H9","H10",
                        "SA","SK","SQ","SJ","S2","S3","S4","S5","S6","S7","S8","S9","S10",
                        "CA","CK","CQ","CJ","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9","C10"};// vector holding all the cards

 // set some values:
for (int i=1; i<52; ++i) myvector.push_back(cards[i]);

// using built-in random generator:
random_shuffle ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end() );

// using myrandom:
random_shuffle ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myrandom);// shuffling so that a cards is not generated twice
  for (std::vector<string>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it){
//std::cout << ' ' << *it;

all_cards.push_back(*it);}//all cards saved at all_cards
for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    player_0.push_back(all_cards[i]);
    player_1.push_back(all_cards[i+9]);
    player_2.push_back(all_cards[i+18]);
    player_3.push_back(all_cards[i+27]);
    player_4.push_back(all_cards[i+36]);
                    }
string x,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,y;
a=player_0[0];b=player_0[1];c=player_0[2];d=player_0[3];e=player_0[4];f=player_0[5];g=player_0[6];
cout<<"player_0 (a)"<<a<<setw(5)<<"(b)"<<b<<setw(5)<<"(c)"<<c<<setw(5)<<"(d)"<<d<<setw(5)<<"(e)"<<e<<setw(5)<<"(f)"<<f<<setw(5)<<"(g)"<<g<<endl;
char choice; // player_0' choice
cout << "which one to replace ?"<<endl;
while(cin >> choice)
{
cout << "which one to replace ?"<<endl;
char check;


switch (choice){  // switch the option the player is choosing
case 'a':
player_1.push_back(player_0[0]);
player_0.erase(player_0.begin());

break;
case 'b':
player_1.push_back(player_0[1]);
player_0.erase(player_0.begin()+1);

break;
case 'c':
player_1.push_back(player_0[2]);
player_0.erase(player_0.begin()+2);

break;
case 'd':
player_1.push_back(player_0[3]);
player_0.erase(player_0.begin()+3);

break;
case 'e':
player_1.push_back(player_0[4]);
player_0.erase(player_0.begin()+4);

break;
case 'f':
player_1.push_back(player_0[5]);
player_0.erase(player_0.begin()+5);

break;
case 'g':
player_1.push_back(g);
player_0.erase(player_0.begin()+6);

break;
case '?':
  cout<<"player_0 (a)"<<a<<setw(5)<<"(b)"<<b<<setw(5)<<"(c)"<<c<<setw(5)<<"(d)"<<d<<setw(5)<<"(e)"<<e<<setw(5)<<"(f)"<<f<<setw(5)<<"(g)"<<g<<endl;
  cout<<"player_1 (a)"<<player_1[0]<<setw(5)<<"(b)"<<player_1[1]<<setw(5)<<"(c)"<<player_1[2]<<setw(5)<<"(d)"<<player_1[3]<<setw(5)<<"(e)"<<player_1[4]<<setw(5)<<"(f)"<<player_1[5]<<setw(5)<<"(g)"<<player_1[6]<<endl;
  cout<<"player_2 (a)"<<player_2[0]<<setw(5)<<"(b)"<<player_2[1]<<setw(5)<<"(c)"<<player_2[2]<<setw(5)<<"(d)"<<player_2[3]<<setw(5)<<"(e)"<<player_2[4]<<setw(5)<<"(f)"<<player_2[5]<<setw(5)<<"(g)"<<player_2[6]<<endl;
  cout<<"player_3 (a)"<<player_3[0]<<setw(5)<<"(b)"<<player_3[1]<<setw(5)<<"(c)"<<player_3[2]<<setw(5)<<"(d)"<<player_3[3]<<setw(5)<<"(e)"<<player_3[4]<<setw(5)<<"(f)"<<player_3[5]<<setw(5)<<"(g)"<<player_3[6]<<endl;
  cout<<"player_4 (a)"<<player_4[0]<<setw(5)<<"(b)"<<player_4[1]<<setw(5)<<"(c)"<<player_4[2]<<setw(5)<<"(d)"<<player_4[3]<<setw(5)<<"(e)"<<player_4[4]<<setw(5)<<"(f)"<<player_4[5]<<setw(5)<<"(g)"<<player_4[6]<<endl;
  cout << endl;
  cout << "which one to replace ?"<<endl;
  break;
default:
break;

}
// checking if the player has the same suit of cards
    if(are_all_same_suit(player_0)==true){
    cout<<"player_0 wins"<<endl;
    break;
    }
    else if(are_all_same_suit(player_1)==true){
    cout<<"player_1 wins" <<endl;
    break;
    }
    else if(are_all_same_suit(player_2)==true){
    cout<<"player_2 wins" <<endl;
    break;
    }
    else if(are_all_same_suit(player_3)==true){
    cout<<"player_3 wins" <<endl;
    break;
    }
    else if(are_all_same_suit(player_4)==true){
    cout<<"player_4 wins" <<endl;
    break;
    }
    else{ // if the player has mismatch cards they choose to obtain different cards
        if(choice=='?'){continue;}
        if(are_all_same_suit(player_1)!=true){
            player_2.push_back(player_1[card_to_move(player_1)]);
            player_1.erase(player_1.begin()+(card_to_move(player_1)));}
        if(are_all_same_suit(player_2)!=true){
            player_3.push_back(player_2[card_to_move(player_2)]);
            player_2.erase(player_2.begin()+(card_to_move(player_2)));

            }
        if(are_all_same_suit(player_3)!=true){
            player_4.push_back(player_3[card_to_move(player_3)]);
            player_3.erase(player_3.begin()+(card_to_move(player_3)));

        }
        if(are_all_same_suit(player_4)!=true){
            player_0.push_back(player_4[card_to_move(player_4)]);
            player_4.erase(player_4.begin()+(card_to_move(player_4)));}
    }a=player_0[0];b=player_0[1];c=player_0[2];d=player_0[3];e=player_0[4];f=player_0[5];g=player_0[6];
    cout<<"(a)"<<a<<setw(5)<<"(b)"<<b<<setw(5)<<"(c)"<<c<<setw(5)<<"(d)"<<d<<setw(5)<<"(e)"<<e<<setw(5)<<"(f)"<<f<<setw(5)<<"(g)"<<g<<endl;
 }
}
```

it is a game where each player is trying to get the same 7 suit of cards.

the error in eclips are as follows:

> 17:48:41 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project my
>   ship sails! **** Info: Internal Builder is used for build g++ -O0 -g3
>   -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\my ship sails!.o" "..\src\my ship sails!.cpp"  ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp: In function 'int
>   card_to_move(std::vector >)':
>   ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:13:10: warning: 'auto' changes meaning in
>   C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
>        for (auto comparison : input)
>             ^ ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:13:15: error: 'comparison' does not name a type
>        for (auto comparison : input)
>                  ^ ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:19:10: error: expected ';' before 'return'
>            }return j;
>             ^ ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:19:10: error: expected primary-expression before 'return' ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:19:10:
>   error: expected ';' before 'return' ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:19:10:
>   error: expected primary-expression before 'return' ..\src\my ship
>   sails!.cpp:19:10: error: expected ')' before 'return' ..\src\my ship
>   sails!.cpp:11:9: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
>        int i =0; int j;
>            ^ ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:12:10: warning: unused variable 'suit' [-Wunused-variable]
>        char suit = input.at(0).at(0);
>             ^ ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp: In function 'bool are_all_same_suit(std::vector >)':
>   ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:24:10: warning: 'auto' changes meaning in
>   C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
>        for (auto comparison : input)
>             ^ ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:24:15: error: 'comparison' does not name a type
>        for (auto comparison : input)
>                  ^ ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:28:5: error: expected ';' before 'return'
>        return true;
>        ^ ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:28:5: error: expected primary-expression before 'return' ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:28:5:
>   error: expected ';' before 'return' ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:28:5:
>   error: expected primary-expression before 'return' ..\src\my ship
>   sails!.cpp:28:5: error: expected ')' before 'return' ..\src\my ship
>   sails!.cpp:23:10: warning: unused variable 'suit' [-Wunused-variable]
>        char suit = input.at(0).at(0);
>             ^ ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp: In function 'int main()': ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:44:94: error: in C++98 'cards' must be
>   initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'
>                                "CA","CK","CQ","CJ","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9","C10"};//
>   vector holding all the cards
>                                                                                                 ^ ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:44:94: error: could not convert '{"DA",
>   "DK", "DQ", "DJ", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9",
>   "D10", "HA", "HK", "HQ", "HJ", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "H7",
>   "H8", "H9", "H10", "SA", "SK", "SQ", "SJ", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5",
>   "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10", "CA", "CK", "CQ", "CJ", "C2", "C3",
>   "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10"}' from '' to 'std::vector >'
>   ..\src\my ship sails!.cpp:73:10: warning: unused variable 'check'
>   [-Wunused-variable]
>        char check;
>             ^
>
> 17:48:44 Build Finished (took 3s.400ms)

Comment: please ignore my indentation. I know it is not quite right. Also i am new to programming so please give me as much detail as possible.

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features

Comment: i couldnot find a solution over in the above link

Comment: Then you didn't read closely enough. The command `g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\my ship sails!.o" "..\\src\\my ship sails!.cpp"` is missing the switch to compile targeting c++11. In the most recent versions of eclipse: project->properties->c/c++ build->settings->tool settings->gcc C++ compiler->dialect. Pick a dialect from the drop-down.